# How do I transfer garbage from my full landfills to my incinerators?

Tags: cities-skylines

Eventually every one of my landfills gets completely full and is constantly blinking at me warning me it's full. I've even built incinerators but they aren't taking the garbage from the landfills. The incinerators are just collecting new garbage. **How do I transfer garbage from the landfills to the incinerators**?

[image: Full Landfills]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was at first a bit confused as to the button "empty building to another facility" thinking that would just move it to another landfill.
In order to move the trash from the landfill to incinerators you **must** click "Empty building to another facility" on your landfill:

[image: Empty]

After you set it to emptying mode garbage trucks will start transferring it to incinerators where it will be burned:

[image: Truck]

Also, just want to point out, this works with cemeteries and crematoriums the exact same way.

Comment: I was going to punch my computer in the face because of this. How did I even miss it >_>

Answer (score 1):

In the case that your having (the landfill moving to another landfill): try turning on "move to another landfill" on all the landfills besides the ones closest to an incinerator that way when the ones closest fill up theyll be forced to unload in an incinerator. At least that's what I did; I turned on all my garbages on right after reading this and started from the inside outward of my city... sure my people where unhappy for a few short years but it didnt really affect much. I agree with the bad logic in the game though. As soon as that button is activated it should immediately unload into an incinerator/crematorium.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like it's bugged. If a landfill is available it will always transfer to another landfill, meaning you can't open a new landfill, effectively, until all landfills are empty. bad logic in code.

Comment: This is not my experience, I successfully emptied the above landfills to incinerators. Perhaps something else was going on in your case, like the incinerators were too far away or something else